# Why is the custom exception I created causing a non-static variable error?

Tags: java, exception, non-static, custom-exceptions

Can somebody please explain what is going on here? Why is the "non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context." appearing in this code? I have tried changing the parseBinary to non-static. I have tried changing the BinaryFormatException class to static... (not allowed). My understanding of this error is very weak. I know I can usually swap some static and public words around and get it to work right. No such luck with this. This is a homework question... but the work does not revolve around the error. It  has to do with creating a custom exception class that is thrown when a binary string is incorrectly formed. So while my question will help me answer the problem, it will not give me the answer.

```
public class binaryToDecimal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println(parseBinary("10001"));
            System.out.println(parseBinary("101111111"));
        } catch (BinaryFormatException ex) {
            ex.getMessage();
        }
    }

    public static int parseBinary(String binaryString)
            throws BinaryFormatException {
        int value = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < binaryString.length(); i++) {
            char ch = binaryString.charAt(i);

            if (ch != '0' && ch != '1') {
                throw new BinaryFormatException(String message);
                value = 0;
            } else
                value = value * 2 + binaryString.charAt(i) - '0';
        }

        return value;
    }

    class BinaryFormatException extends Exception {
        public BinaryFormatException(String message) {
            super(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "I have tried changing the BinaryFormatException class to static... (not allowed)." What was the change? What was the exact change you made and what error did you get? As the answers point out that is exactly what you need to do.

Comment: Sorry this in a tough question to answer because I tried swapping so many things around. I eventually figured out what I needed to do thanks to the help you all provided and some additional "poke and hope" techniques. I posted my solution down at the bottom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you've defined `BinaryFormatException` as an inner class to your public class `binaryToDecimal`.  That means that you need an instance of `binaryToDecimal` to have an instance of `BinaryFormatException`.  However, you are in the `static` context of the `parseBinary` method.  There is no instance of `binaryToDecimal`.

You have two choices:

1. Declare the `BinaryFormatException` class `static`.
2. Move the `BinaryFormatException` class code outside of the `binaryToDecimal` class.

Comment: +1. Also note that `throw new BinaryFormatException(String message);` will not work. Do `throw new BinaryFormatException("message");` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Because BinaryFormatException is an inner class of BinaryToDecimal, so it needs an outer instance to create one. However, parseBinary is a static method, and it runs without a instance of the class.

Put the word "static" before "class BinaryFormat Exception" to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your responses. This is the answer I finally came up with a few minutes ago that seems to work properly.

```
    public class binaryToDecimal extends parseBinary{

       public static void main( String[] args ){
           try {
               System.out.println(parseBinary( "10001"  ));
               System.out.println(parseBinary( "141111111" ));
           } catch (BinaryFormatException ex) {
               ex.printStackTrace();
           }
          }
    }

class parseBinary{
    String binaryString = "";
   public static int parseBinary(String binaryString ) throws BinaryFormatException
      {
      int value = 0;

      for (int i = 0; i < binaryString.length(); i++)
         {
         char ch = binaryString.charAt(i);

         if (ch != '0' && ch != '1'){
            //value = value * 2 + binaryString.charAt(i) - '0';
         throw new BinaryFormatException("Invalid format at: " + ch + " in binaryString parameter.");
         }else{         
            value = value * 2 + binaryString.charAt(i) - '0';
         }

      }
            return value;

   }
}
class BinaryFormatException extends Exception{
    public BinaryFormatException(String message){
        super(message);
    }
}
```